# scala merge option sequences

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-option

Want to merge `val A = Option(Seq(1,2))` and `val B = Option(Seq(3,4))` to yield a new option sequence

`val C = Option(Seq(1,2,3,4))`

This

`val C = Option(A.getOrElse(Nil) ++ B.getOrElse(Nil))`,

seems faster and more idiomatic than

`val C = Option(A.toList.flatten ++ B.toList.flatten)`

But is there a better way? And am I right that `getOrElse` is faster and lighter than `toList.flatten`?

Comment: When you say "faster", do you mean "has someone else performed benchmarks on this code"? Unlikely. However, the first example does not require a type conversion (`toList`).

Comment: I'd prefer your first approach to any of the current answers.

Comment: @BobDalgleish yes, my feeling was that the first option has fewer conversions and thus preferable.

Answer (score 3):

What about a neat for comprehension:

```
val Empty = Some(Nil)

val C = for {
  a <- A orElse Empty
  b <- B orElse Empty
} yield a ++ b
```

Creates less intermediate options.

Or, you could just do a somewhat cumbersome pattern matching:

```
(A, B) match {
  case (None, None) => Nil
  case (None, sb@Some(b)) => sb
  case (sa@Some(a), None) => sa
  case (Some(a), Some(b)) => Some(a ++ b)
}
```

I think this at least creates less intermediate collections than the double flatten.

Answer (score 2):

Your first case:

```
// In this case getOrElse is not needed as the option is clearly not `None`.
// So, you can replace the following: 
val C = Option(A.getOrElse(Nil) ++ B.getOrElse(Nil))

// By this:
val C = Option(A.get ++ B.get) // A simple concatenation of two sequences.
C: Option[Seq[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

Your second case/option is wrong for multiple reasons.

```
val C = Option(A.toList.flatten ++ B.toList.flatten)

    Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

1. It returns the incorrect type Option[List[Int]] instead of Option[Seq[Int]]
2. It needlessly invokes `toList` on A & B. You could simply add the options and invoke `flatten` on them.
3. It is not DRY and redundantly calls `flatten` on both `A.toList` & `B.toList` whereas it could call flatten on `(A ++ B)`

Instead of this, you could do this more efficiently:

```
val E = Option((A ++ B).flatten.toSeq) 
E: Option[Seq[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

Comment: In my situation the Option could be None, so I don't think `.get` will suffice. Thanks for clarifying the problems with the second case.

Answer (score 1):

Using `foldLeft`

```
Seq(Some(List(1, 2)), None).foldLeft(List.empty[Int])(_ ++ _.getOrElse(List.empty[Int]))
result: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

Using `flatten` twice

```
Seq(Some(Seq(1, 2, 3)), Some(4, 5, 6), None).flatten.flatten

result: Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> val a = Some(Seq(1, 2, 3))
a: Some[Seq[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2, 3))

scala> val b = Some(Seq(4, 5, 6))
b: Some[Seq[Int]] = Some(List(4, 5, 6))

scala> val c = None
c: None.type = None

scala> val d = Seq(a, b, c).flatten.flatten
d: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```